# Is the email cloaking feature in Joomla 1.5 useful at all? better alternatives?

Tags: javascript, joomla1.5, spam-prevention

I just noticed that the built-in plugin for email cloaking in Joomla 1.5 is not working as good as expected. It turns out Google can process JavaScript nowadays which exposes the email addresses. I imagine it would be easy for a spammer to create a script that googles every domain name with an "@" sign at the beginning to expose all email addresses on each website.

I liked the antispam feature in Joomla because it did the job without any hassle. And the visitors wouldn't experience any problems, the emails and the email links would appear to them as usual. I don't like to have to use forms or annoying `CAPTCHA's`. My philosophy is that usability should not be affected because of spammers. I do use and I do recommend a spam quarantine, but if the email addresses weren't exposed and sold in the first place, that would be way better and save some time.

So my question is if my observation is correct that JavaScript email protection is now outdated and what are the alternatives that have the least impact on usability?

Comment: Where does it say Google processes JavaScript? I see no reason for them to do so.

Comment: I noticed it when i googled an address of my own website. All email addresses on that page were displayed in the SERP. The page has had the JavaScript spam protection for years now. If i go to the website and click CTRL+U (source) I can't find the the emails addresses or even parts of them, but I can see the JavaScript code in its place.

Comment: Why, it seems that [you're right](http://searchengineland.com/google-can-now-execute-ajax-javascript-for-indexing-99518).

Comment: Nice find. I just find it strange that I can't find anyone who has similar questions regarding antispam. I thought Joomla powered like 1% of the entire web or more? Not to mention all other JavaScript cloaking methods out there that are probably useless now.